# Tank tracks/treads breaking when rotating hull

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh

I am working on an m1 abrams model and I plan on using it in an animation but I have encountered a problem.

[image: I am quite proud in achieving this only after 1 week of learning blender]

I've parented the bezier circle to the hull and all works well when the tank is going straight, but then... i tried rotating it...

[image: An it has hands a feet]

Its probably some amateurish mistake but I'm new and i cant find a solution.
googled it, the answers were mostly years ago so I'll also contribute by having a newer thread to look by everyone else

Comment: Is you project for video or an authentic model?  I've done this with a full mesh solution, and also one that fakes the track-plates' animation.  Both come out ok for video work, and both render in OpenGL so a lot of experimental rendering can be done very quickly. The  problem is, a fair bit of experience will be required, particularly for the mesh solution and a full answer will take a lot of typing.  I've been holding back to see if someone else will come up with a smarter ( and easier) method.  (I'm still using vers 2.77a)

Comment: PS to the above - If no one comes up with something you can take the experimental blend files and have a look if you think that might help.   I can embed a quickie text-file explanation in each.

Comment: @Edgel3D Expermental blend files? sorry for such a slow reply I was working on a new project and expermenting.

Comment: Noted your reply @NlaEid.  Will get back as soon as I can.  Is this for a video project or game?

Comment: Hold the Presses @NlaEid !  I knew there had to be a better way...  Have deleted the workaround answer and substituted with another, which you'll find much easier.  My original tank tracks made years ago suffered  the same problem as yours, hence the workarounds.  I've been chewing over the reason why the screw effect and have come up with the simple answer - we just put them together wrong!  See how you go with the current solution. (see below)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Edit 13th Feb 2019 - Added Blend file for a query in 'Blender Artists'.

-===============-

The answer is in the way it's all put together, particularly the Origin points.  The Curve, Tracks and Empty must all share the same OP.

The steps below (deleted) cured my original tracks that I'd made ages ago and like yours, suffered badly with the screw effect when rotated in the Z axis.

I did this one with a single track, and duplicated it after.
[image]

[image]

The Details -

Delete all parentage and also delete the Empty.

Select the tank tracks and remove the curve modifier.

"Apply" the array modifier as it stands.  (make it solid)

Set the cursor to 0,0,0 with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>,

Select the tracks, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> --> "Selected to Cursor".

Select the curve, and do the same (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>)

With the tracks selected again, replace the curve modifier.

Add an empty with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>.

Parent the tracks to the Empty

Parent the Curve to the Empty.

That should do it - you can rotate and move the Empty now without ill effects...

If this hasn't worked the 3D cursor may have been inadvertently moved from location 0,0,0.