# convert curve animation to keyframes

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, baking

Hy everyone

I've got a caterpillar/tank tracks, with several individual track parts. With the Curve modifier, they go around the curve and behave as they should.

The animation is a loop animation for a game. So all the track-parts move just one part forward and then jump back. Played the right way (looping) it's completely seamless.

The problem is, the current animation keyframes are, because of the curve modifier along the curves y-axis and are location-keyframes.
With the "Object->animation->bake keyframes", after applying the curve modifier, they just move in the y-direction and not in the way the curve path was.

Finally, I want keyframes for all these objects (for a action) and all objects without any modifier go this one step.

Thanks in advance for your answers

Quados

Comment: I have done this when my tracks skewed off and didn't follow the tank's rotation in the z axis.  The proper answer was to redo the track plates and curve from scratch so they shared the same origin point. (exactly)  Before realising this I solved the skewing problem by eliminating the modifiers altogether.  It's not for the faint hearted and I deleted that answer, replacing it with the Common Origin point solution.  It did remove the need for modifiers though and the tracks' rotation were then keyframed. You can have the Blend file etc if you think it might solve your problem.

Comment: Added to the above - Before you go down that rather complex path you might like to check this out first - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108834/tank-tracks-treads-breaking-when-rotating-hull/110070#110070

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. I will try to do it, as you have described, as soon as I continue working on that project.

Comment: No the problem isn't solved, with the curve modifier, I set keyframes for the y-location and NOT for the location/rotation of the caterpillar-track-piece.

Comment: So you need the alternative ? - remove the modifiers altogether, keyframe the track plates' rotation around the Cogs?  As mentioned, I've already deleted that answer but I've placed the Mesh rotation version Blend file on dropbox.  The text is embedded as a packed image in an Empty.  It's called ATT in layer 1.  If this solves your problem, or the second alternative also described there. (Blend file available) , let me know and I'll try and resubmit it as an answer here.  Last time I tried to replace a gif though, it wouldn't allow it.  Best of luck - it worked fine for me.

Comment: Further to the above - the Dropbox link -  https://www.dropbox.com/s/35dtvgka986cpco/TankTracksWorkaround.zip?dl=0 -  If you're asked to log in, just click in an empty space.