# Snowmobile path creation

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves, transforms

I tried a lot of times and different ways to create my path. Its like a tank path.I didnt make it. Just tired to trying a lot of times because when i move my vehicle path deforms.Can someone help me to create a snowmobile path correctly ? the problem is this 
[image] i can't solve this its always deforming if i move it.Can someone help?

Comment: Confess, I'm unsure of your problem, but can this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108834/tank-tracks-treads-breaking-when-rotating-hull/110070#110070

Comment: To add to the above, the shape of the tank tracks were distorting and even breaking up when moved.  The procedure set out at the link, fixed the problem.  In your case there'd be no 'tracks' or animation around the curve.  You just have to move it with the circular Empty.  Parent the entire model's parts, including the curve to that and drag the Empty for movement.

Comment: @Edgel3D are you want to say model the path and animate the movement ?

Comment: @Edgel3D ''To add to the above, the shape of the tank tracks were distorting and even breaking up when moved'' Yes !

Comment: @Edgel3D omg looks like it solved.What a site ! its my first ask and answered very quickly. lel . I hope i will dont come back to this question.