# Tank tracks not rotating properly

Tags: animation

When I rotate the body along the X axis the tracks stick to the curve just fine. However, when I rotate along the Z or Y axis the tracks no longer stick to the curve as seen in the photo.[image: Tracks no longer connected to the curve]

[image]

Comment: hello, maybe share your file, at least the important parts, i.e. armature + tracks, use this site: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: This might help - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108834/tank-tracks-treads-breaking-when-rotating-hull/110070#110070

Comment: @Edgel3D I just did that but after I parent both the track and the curve to the empty, moving the empty just moves the whole thing without making the tracks rotate around the curve.

Comment: That would be right, you have to drag or keyframe the respective tracks' origin points (going on memory) to rotate them around the curve.  Take another peek at the reference video.

Comment: @Edgel3D How do you get the origin point dragging thing to appear? I downloaded your .blend file and I really don't understand how it works

Comment: This was some time ago, so I've got to get back into that for an accurate answer but as I remember it, simply select each track and it's origin point will be where the gismo arrows appear.  Drag the coloured arrows in one of the axis'.  You can do that in the included Blend file as shown in the video.  The tracks will rotate around the curve.