# How to keep arrayed object from breaking after rotation?

Tags: modifiers

I intend to make tracks, like the ones on a tank, and I am using an array modifier and a curve modifier. It works great when I move the curve on a specific axis. However, as soon as I rotate it or I move it on any other axis, it breaks.

In the first picture, you can see the array and curve modifiers. The Mirror modifier isn't the problem. I have shown just the track here
[image]

Here I moved the object on the y axis, the same axis as the curve is set on. I noticed that I can only move it on the axis that it was set to without it 'breaking'
[image]

I rotated it here slightly just to show what it looks like when it is rotated. I plan to use this for animation so I can't apply the modifiers and I still need the tracks to move.
[image]

Comment: Try moving the curve, not the array

Comment: Try parenting everything to an empty and use the empty to rotate?

Comment: @lwswl Moving the curve does not fix the problem. The same thing happens

Comment: This might help -

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108834/tank-tracks-treads-breaking-when-rotating-hull/110070#110070